# ElementUI message initial render disable

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, element-ui

been trying to use https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/message
in my component via

```
import Message from "@/components/ElementUi/Message";
```

and inside that component just normal include from element-ui

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-button :plain="true" @click="open">{{label}}</el-button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { Message, Button } from "element-ui";
// import lang from "element-ui/lib/locale/lang/ru-RU";
// import locale from "element-ui/lib/locale";

import "element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css";
import "../../../public/css/element-variables.scss";
//locale.use(lang);
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.use(Message);
Vue.use(Button);
export default {
  props: ["label", "content", "type", "duration", "run"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    open() {
      Message({
        showClose: true,
        message: this.content,
        type: this.type,
        duration: this.duration,
        dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true
      });
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (this.run == 1) {
      // this.open();
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {}
};
</script>
```

What happens when my component updates this annoying message automatically display with 0 content, but I want to to be rendered only when some conditions are met 
like

```
<div
          v-if="searchCompleted.status && searchCompleted.codingType=='reverse' && searchCompleted.fullMatch == false "
        >
          <message
            :duration="3000"
            :label="'info'"
            :content="'<p>No data</p>'"
            :type="'message'"
          ></message>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The documentation lacks of information how not to show the element on initial render of component, so there must be some pure javascript option how to disable that thing and enable when needed?

Comment: Have you imported Element UI in your entire project? Or are you just using the Message component for the project?

Comment: I am trying to use it locally in order to minimize bundle size not sure if it helps as on different pages I use only 1-2 elements of Element Ui